# CompletableFuture - Run multiple rest calls in parallel and get different result

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, java-8, completable-future

I have a rather common or unique requirement. For example, I have the following `AccountDetails` list:

`List<AccountDetails>`

```
class AccountDetails {
    String bankAccountId;
    String mortgageAccountId;
    Integer noOfTrans;
    String addressLine;
    String externalLink;   
}
```

All the above fields, except `bankAccountId` are pulled from external REST service call.
I want to call all the REST services in parallel and update each object in the list:

So, it looks like below:

For each `accountDetails`

- Call mortgage REST service and update `martgageAccountId`field (REST returns MortgageInfo object)
- Call transaction REST service and update `noOfTrans` field (REST returns `Transactions` object)
- Call address REST service and update `addressLine` field (REST returns `Address` object)
- Call link REST service and update `externalLink` field.  (REST returns `Links` object)

I want all the above calls in parallel, and for each `AcccountDetails` object in the list.
If there is an exception, I want do gracefully handle it. Note that each of the above REST service returns different custom object

I am confused about how to achieve this with `CompletableFuture` chaining.
Not sure `allOf` or `thenCombine` (which only takes two), or `thenCompose` should use and how to put all of these together.

Any examples/ideas?

Comment: One thing I would try to avoid is calling the endpoint for every object. If there are bulk requests on your backend services you should defer to those. So you would collect all ids then make one request to the backend service.

Comment: @SamOrozco You are right. But the calls are cached. So individual calls are better than bulk, thats the reason looping through single record

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
AccountDetails accountDetails = new AccountDetails();

CompletableFuture.allOf(
                        CompletableFuture.
                                supplyAsync(() -> //CALL MORTAGE INFO REST, executor).
                                thenAccept(x -> {
                                    accountDetails.setMortgageAccountId(x.getReqdField())
                                }).
                                handle(//HANDLE GRACEFULLY),
                        CompletableFuture.
                                supplyAsync(() -> //CALL SOME OTHER REST, executor).
                                thenAccept(x -> {
                                    accountDetails.setNoOfTrans(x.getReqdField())
                                }).
                                handle(//HANDLE GRACEFULLY),
                        CompletableFuture.
                                supplyAsync(() -> //CALL SOME INFO REST, executor).
                                thenAccept(x -> {
                                    accountDetails.setAddressLine(x.getReqdField())
                                }).
                                handle(//HANDLE GRACEFULLY),
                        CompletableFuture.
                                supplyAsync(() -> //CALL SOME OTHER REST, executor).
                                thenAccept(x -> {
                                    accountDetails.setExternalLink(x.getReqdField())
                                }).
                                handle(//HANDLE GRACEFULLY),
                ).join();
```

Comment: What is `handle()` and what goes in there? Also, I have list of `AccountDetails`, so I will put the whole stuff above in a loop `Stream`. So that means, each loop runs a new thread and under each thread, about 4 new threads run?

Comment: handle() -> Returns a new CompletionStage that, when this stage completes either normally or exceptionally, is executed with this stage's result and exception as arguments to the supplied function.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#handle-java.util.function.BiFunction-


Yes, you can run the loop for the list of account details and populate it using the completable future given above, each loop run will not necessarily run on the different thread.

Comment: Whenever you're using CompletableFuture.supplyAsync or CompletableFuture.supplyAsync you always want to provide your own executor. Using the default forkjoin pool doesn't have very many threads available and will almost always cause calls to back up.

Comment: What is the difference between `join()` at the end of `allOf()` vs at each `supplyAsyc()`?

Answer (score 6):

If I simply a bit your account class as:

```
class Account {
  String fieldA;
  String fieldB;
  String fieldC;

  Account(String fieldA, String fieldB, String fieldC) {
    this.fieldA = fieldA;
    this.fieldB = fieldB;
    this.fieldC = fieldC;
  }
}
```

Then you can use `CompletableFuture#allOf(...)` to wait the results of all the completable future, one per field update, and then retrieve the result from those futures individually. We cannot use the result of `allOf` because it returns nothing (void).

```
Account account = CompletableFuture.allOf(cfA, cfB, cfC)
    .thenApply(ignored -> {
      String a = cfA.join();
      String b = cfB.join();
      String c = cfC.join();
      return new Account(a, b, c);
    }).join(); // or get(...) with timeout
```

We can use join in the `thenApply` because all the completable futures are done at this stage. You can modify the code block above to adapt your logic, such as updating fields instead of creating a new object. Note that the `join()` above can raise exception when the completable future is completed exceptionally. You can either change your completable future to `handle()` it correctly before submitting the future to `allOf(...)`, or ask if it `isCompletedExceptionally()` before using the `join()`:

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(cfA, cfB, cfC)
    .thenRun(() -> {
      if (!cfA.isCompletedExceptionally()) {
        account.fieldA = cfA.join();
      }
      if (!cfB.isCompletedExceptionally()) {
        account.fieldB = cfB.join();
      }
      if (!cfC.isCompletedExceptionally()) {
        account.fieldC = cfC.join();
      }
    }).join(); // or get(...) with timeout
```

The benefit of updating fields inside one completion stage is that these operations are done in the same thread so you don't have to worry about concurrent modification.

Comment: Help me understand. Isn't `join()` a blocking operation?

Comment: @KevinRave, `allOf()` completes is completed when all of the given CompletableFutures complete, so `allOf()` is blocking the operation, and `join()` only retrieve the results.

Comment: What is the difference between `join()` at the end of `allOf()` vs at each `supplyAsyc()` like in the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62841165/668650)?

Comment: @KevinRave, as you said, `join()` is a blocking operation. So we should avoid using `join()` whenever possible to make the entire logic non-blocking. If we perform a `join()` after each `supplyAsync()`, those asynchronous logic become synchronous and blocks the current thread until their execution is complete (either successfully or exceptionally). On the other side, using `join()` at the end of `allOf()` reduces the number of blocking operations, i.e. blocking the current thread once instead of N times.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have tagged `spring-boot` I supposed you use it and your services are written in spring framework. so then I provided an answer that is related to spring framework.

first of all, I created an interface for implementing rest API as async.

```
public interface AsyncRestCall<T> {
   /** this is a hypothetical method with hypothetical params!*/
   CompletableFuture<T> call(String bankAccountId); 
   String type();
}
```

then you can have implementation for your service such this:

As you see in this implementation I've used `MortgageRest` that it represents a rest service for `Mortgage`.

```
 @Service
 public class MortgageService implements AsyncRestCall<MortgageInfo> {

   private final MortgageRest mortgageRest;

   @Autowired
   public MortgageService(MortgageRest mortgageRest) {
       this.mortgageRest = mortgageRest;
   }

   @Override
   public CompletableFuture<MortgageInfo> call(String bankAccountId) {
       return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> mortgageRest.service(bankAccountId));
    }

   @Override
   public String type() {
      return "mortgage";
   } 
}
```

Mortgage Rest:

```
@Service
public class MortgageRest {
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;
  public MortgageRest(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
     this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
  }
  public MortgageInfo service(String bankAccountId) {
     return new MortgageInfo("123455" + bankAccountId);
  }
}
```

for other rest services do such this.

```
@Service
public class TransactionService implements AsyncRestCall<Transactions> {

   private final TransactionRest transactionRest;

   public TransactionService(TransactionRest transactionRest) {
      this.transactionRest = transactionRest;
   } 

   @Override
   public CompletableFuture<Transactions> call(String bankAccountId) {
       return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(transactionRest::service);
   }

   @Override
   public String type() {
       return "transactions";
   } 
}
```

TransactionRest:

```
 @Service
 public class TransactionRest {

   public Transactions service() {
       return new Transactions(12);
   }
 }
```

now you need to have access all `AsyncRestCall` implementations. for this porpuse you can declare a class something like this:

```
@Service
public class RestCallHolder {

  private final List<AsyncRestCall> asyncRestCalls;

  public RestCallHolder(List<AsyncRestCall> asyncRestCalls) {
      this.asyncRestCalls = asyncRestCalls;
  }

  public List<AsyncRestCall> getAsyncRestCalls() {
      return asyncRestCalls;
  }
}
```

`AccountDetailService`(you can name what thing you like) uses `CompleteableFuture` to call rest services as parallel.

in this servie each `bankAccountId` rest calls will store in a `Map<String, Map<String, Object>> result = new HashMap<>();` that outer map key will store `bankAccountId` value as key and its value is rest services calls that they will store in a map(inner map). key is type and value is rest call response. at the end by looping over accountDetails will update its properties.

```
@Service
public class AccountDetailService {

  private final RestCallHolder restCallHolder;

  public AccountDetailService(RestCallHolder restCallHolder) {
      this.restCallHolder = restCallHolder;
  }

  public List<AccountDetail> update(List<AccountDetail> accountDetails) {
     Map<String, Map<String, Object>> result = new HashMap<>();
     List<AccountDetail> finalAccountDetails = new ArrayList<>();

     accountDetails.forEach(accountDetail -> {
          List<CompletableFuture> futures = restCallHolder.getAsyncRestCalls()
                    .stream()
                    .map(rest -> rest.call(accountDetail.getBankAccountId()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

     CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture<?>[0]))
                 .thenAccept(aVoid -> { 
                    Map<String, Object> res = restCallHolder.getAsyncRestCalls()
                              .stream()
                              .map(rest -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(rest.type(),
                                  rest.call(accountDetail.getBankAccountId()).join()))
                              .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
                           result.put(accountDetail.getBankAccountId(), res);
                      }
                   ).handle((aVoid, throwable) -> {
                      return null; // handle the exception here 
             }).join();
            }
    );

      accountDetails.forEach(accountDetail -> finalAccountDetails.add(AccountDetail.builder()
             .bankAccountId(accountDetail.getBankAccountId())
             .mortgageAccountId(((MortgageInfo) result.get(accountDetail.getBankAccountId()).get("mortgage")).getMortgageAccountId())
             .noOfTrans(((Transactions) result.get(accountDetail.getBankAccountId()).get("transactions")).getNoOfTrans())
             .build()));
     return finalAccountDetails;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Whenever you're using `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` or `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` you always want to provide your own executor. Using the default forkjoin pool doesn't have very many threads available and will almost always cause calls to back up.

Answer (score 1):

I would give the responsibility to fetch the field values to the model object itself.
Here are three alternative solutions, using parallel streams, streams and an executor, and a for loop and an executor.

Solution 1:

```
accounts.parallelStream()
        .<Runnable>flatMap(account -> Stream.of(account::updateMortgage, account::updateNoOfTrans,
                account::updateAddressLine, account::updateExternalLink))
        .map(RestRequest::new)
        .forEach(RestRequest::run);
```

Solution 2:

```
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(PARALLELISM);
accounts.stream()
        .<Runnable>flatMap(account -> Stream.of(account::updateMortgage, account::updateNoOfTrans,
                account::updateAddressLine, account::updateExternalLink))
        .map(RestRequest::new)
        .forEach(executor::execute);
```

Solution 3:

```
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(PARALLELISM);
for (AccountDetails account : accounts) {
    execute(executor, account::updateMortgage);
    execute(executor, account::updateNoOfTrans);
    execute(executor, account::updateAddressLine);
    execute(executor, account::updateExternalLink);
}

private static void execute(Executor executor, Runnable task) {
    executor.execute(new RestRequest(task));
}
```

Common code:

```
class RestRequest implements Runnable {
    private final Runnable task;

    RestRequest(Runnable task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            task.run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // A request failed. Others will not be canceled.
        }
    }
}

class AccountDetails {
    String bankAccountId;
    String mortgageAccountId;
    Integer noOfTrans;
    String addressLine;
    String externalLink;

    void fetchMortgage() {
        mortgageAccountId = MortgageService.getMortgage(bankAccountId).getAccountId();
    }

    void fetchNoOfTrans() {
        noOfTrans = TransactionService.getTransactions(bankAccountId).getAmount();
    }

    void fetchAddressLine() {
        addressLine = AddressService.getAddress(bankAccountId).getLine();
    }

    void fetchExternalLink() {
        externalLink = LinkService.getLinks(bankAccountId).getExternal();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't agree with the responsibility of fetching the external to put on the model.

Comment: How is it efficient and performant compared to [the below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62841165/668650) below